# Built-in image uploader falls over

Tags: support, bug, images

So, I'm trying to upload a photo of some NM in my basement so I can ask questions about its provenance and condition (its inside a half-faced partition wall underneath some stairs).  Thing is, the image-inserter widget goes through the upload process, then triggers the SE framebuster:

[image: The page at diy.stackexchange.com says: For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames.]

and promptly lands me on the diy.SE error page after I click OK.  Should I just shove the images on imgur/... and let someone else rehost them on stack.imgur b/c I can't push them to the Stack imgur directly?

I'm using Chromium Version 35.0.1916.153 (r274914) btw.

Comment: What format are the images? I've seen this problem with .png files. Converting the files to .jpg has allowed me to upload the photos, when I've had this problem.

Comment: They are .jpg, but large (about 6MB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had someone run into this on another site and when I investigated, it appears that Stack Exchange's relationship with imgur.com (the image hosting service that Stack Exchange uses) does not allow for images greater than 2MBytes in size.

Source (sadly, this was the best I could find at the time): ["For security reasons, framing is not allowed; click OK to remove the frames." on Imgur upload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133138/for-security-reasons-framing-is-not-allowed-click-ok-to-remove-the-frames-o)

Try adjusting your camera settings for lower quality images, or use photo editing software to crop or scale them before uploading.